# Why does the following limit not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The limit is $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sqrt y}{\sqrt x}$$  I thought it was 1.

Also what about $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ y}{ x}$$

Comment: undefined for negative

Comment: Complex numbers exist then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $(y_n)=(\frac{1}{n})$ and $(x_n)=(\frac{1}{n^2})$. Then evaluate $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{y_n}{x_n}$.

Answer (score 11):

If any of the limits existed, then all the sublimits (for each case) would coincide. So take the limits along the parabolas $y=kx^2$ to find different sublimits.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus You're welcome.

Comment: Note that even if all the limits $y = kx$ coincide, they may still not exist (if you instead approach by $y = k x^2$...). This is a method to disprove, not prove.

Comment: @Davidmh My intent is to take the limit from the first quadrant. But there's no need to have such complications, so I changed my answer to consider parabolas.

Comment: What I meant is that, if from different paths you get different results, then it does not exist; but you cannot try all possible ways of getting there. There is at least one example where $y=kx$ converges, but $y=kx^2$ doesn't; and I am sure there are the oposite too... or cases where both converge but the limit still does not exist. The core of the issue is that you cannot try *all* possible ways of approaching your point.